# response type incompatible in angular

Tags: json, spring, angular

I'm working with Angular 5 and Spring Backend. In a request I'm return a string.

Backend code:

```
 @PostMapping(value = "login")
public ResponseEntity<?> verifyLogin(@RequestBody String login){
    System.out.println("LOGIN REALIZADO");
    LoginObject loginO = gson.fromJson(login, LoginObject.class);

    if(verify(loginO)){
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("AAA",HttpStatus.OK);
    }else{
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("ERROR-LOGIN",HttpStatus.OK);
    }


}
```

As you can see, I return AAA or ERROR-LOGIN.

And in my frontend I receive this using this code:

```
 loginQuery(login: Login):Observable<string>{
     return this.http.post<string>('http://localhost:8080/login',JSON.stringify(login),{ responseType: 'text' as 'text'});
 }
```

This is working fine. Because I can print AAA in console of my browser. But... the console (of Intellij) shows this error:

> ERROR in src/app/login/sevices/login.service.ts(15,68): error TS2345:
>   Argument of type '{ responseType: "text"; }' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]:
>   string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.   Types of
>   property 'responseType' are incompatible.
>       Type '"text"' is not assignable to type '"json"'.

And my program stops running. What I can do? I need receive this string and work with it.

Answer (score 4):

You should create headers, not give a random object to it.

Or, you can type your random object as any, to bypass the error (nastier but easier).

```
return this.http.post<string>('URL', {}, { responseType: 'text'} as any);
```